# DirectX 11: Draw calls amount

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

Is there a way to see the amount of draw calls in runtime?

Maybe there is a simple directX method for that?

I've thought about making a variable that just hold the amount of times I call Draw() or DrawIndexed() but that seems a little "stupid".

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you used the [Visual Studio Graphics Diagnostics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873207.aspx) in Visual Studio 2013 or 2015? It's included in the Community and Pro+ editions.

Answer (score 3):

This is not stupid to keep a counter to track your call counts. And no, there is nothing simpler than that.

You have `D3D11_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTICS` for queries, but it is not exactly the same, it is lower level, for the draw call count, the code side user counter is what you are looking for.